# Indexing numpy array using boolean vector

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy.ndarray and I have a boolean list. I want to use the list to access the columns in the array.

```
X = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
Y = [True,False,False,True]
```

I want the result to be

```
[[1,4][5,8]]
```

I guess I am doing this inefficiently and would like to know if there is a straightforward method.

Comment: ..... `X[:,Y]`?

Comment: `X[:,[0,3]]`?..

Comment: Nope doesn't work. It says too many indices for array.

Comment: @Nivi, Divakar's answer should work, unless your sample input does not reflect your actual data's characteristics. I'd advise you to revisit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert it to numpy first.

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]])
Y = np.array([True,False,False,True])

print(X[:,Y])
```

Comment: did you convert your array into numpy?

Comment: I did the copy/paste, and it works just as you'd like.

Comment: Yes it does. My 
y = array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)

Will check. Thanks.

Comment: @ it should be np.array, not just array. Can you please put your actual code in the question? if it is still not working.